# Implementation of loopback-component-passport for LDAP/MS-AD doesn't work

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap, passport.js, loopbackjs

I'm trying to implement **loopback-component-passport** and **passport-ldapauth**, however using it in the way one would use it for authenticating with facebook doesn't seem to be working.

Essentailly, I've copied the provider.json properties from:

```
"ms-ad": {
"provider": "ms-ad",
"authScheme":"ldap",
"module": "passport-ldapauth",
"authPath": "/auth/msad",
"successRedirect": "/auth/account",
"failureRedirect": "/msad",
"failureFlash": true,
"session": true,
"LdapAttributeForLogin": "mail",
"LdapAttributeForUsername": "mail",
"LdapAttributeForMail": "mail",
"server":{
  "url": "ldap://ldap.example.org:389/dc=example,dc=org",
  "bindDn": "bindUsername",
  "bindCredentials": "bindPassword",
  "searchBase": "ou=people,dc=example,dc=org",
  "searchAttributes": ["cn", "mail", "uid", "givenname"],
  "searchFilter": "(&(objectcategory=person)(objectclass=user)(|(samaccountname={{username}})(mail={{username}})))"
}
```

But I can't seem to get it to authenticate via */auth/msad*. Does anyone have experience with this? I know we can likely do it much easier if using `var LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth')` and `passport.use(LdapStrategy....)` but I'd like to see this working because the documentation implies little more config is needed.